# TypeError: OrbitControls is not a constructor in angular2

Tags: angular, three.js

I am working on angular2 with three.js.

Here is my configuration of angular cli.

In the package.json:

```
"three": "^0.81.2",
"three-stl-loader": "^1.0.4",
```

In the angular.cli.json:

```
    "../node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
    "../node_modules/three/examples/js/Detector.js",
    "../node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js",
    "../node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js",
    "../node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js",
```

In the component file, I loaded the THREE and OrbitControls:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';    
import PerspectiveCamera = THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
import OrbitControls = THREE.OrbitControls;
```

When the application runs, there is the following message from the console:

```
'THREE.WebGLRenderer 81
three.js:41149 THREE.WebGLRenderer: .shadowMapEnabled is now .shadowMap.enabled.
three.js:41158 THREE.WebGLRenderer: .shadowMapType is now .shadowMap.type.
'
```

So it is clear three.js is loaded, but why OrbitControls can not be found?

Comment: OrbitControls is not apart of the Three.js framework. It exists in a subdirectory called Examples, and it does not use ES6 import / export syntax. Therefore, you'll need to use a third party NPM module.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue. Here was my work around, run the following command:

```
npm install three-orbit-controls
```

Edit the component.ts file under your import statements but above @Component:

```
const THREE = require('three');
const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);
```

Now it will be referred to as just OrbitControls instead of THREE.OrbitControls